# Moving an Object to A Point

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Another relatively simple question I hope.
I have a person object that I move to a point designated by a point on a screen touched by the user.
I would like to have a set speed that the object moves to the position in.
However I am not sure how to do it as every time I calculate it it either has varying speeds or the x origin gets there before the y origin and vice versa.
I would like to be able to move them at the same speed and have them reach the point at the same time.
I hope I have explained this well, if not please ask questions
Thanks in advance
Disco

Comment: how do you implement moving now? is person is some kind of uiview?

Comment: good question. I am using an opengl view and each time it draws it calls a method in my Player object to calculate its position depending on the position touched by the user. If its not at that position it adds something to x and y of the player object. My player object is a vertex and im moving it using its x and  y

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your update function, calculate the X and Y distance from point A to point B, and each frame increment the difference by the same *fraction* rather than a constant value.

i.e. `player.X += difference / frameCount`.

Comment: Will i not then get varying distances because as the difference changes I'm going to get different values to increment by?

Answer (score 0):

Well, speed is distance * time, and what you need is an instance of NSTimer. Use timerWithTimeInterval:invocation:repeats: and have it invoke a moveObject method. The moveObject method move the object by a certain distance each time it is called until the object's object's location is equal to the destination's location. Then the moveObject method invalidates the timer and Bob's your uncle.

---UPDATE----
Wouldn't you know it, no sooner had I written this and what do I see? UIView animateWithDuration:animations: . Which is the above, but, like, way easier. At least, I hope so for I haven't used it myself. Yet.